# Use mvc routing to alias a action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a `ApiController` called `MyControllerName` and action `MyActionName`.
Url to call this method: `api/MyControllerName/MyActionName`
I would like to add a route so that this method can also be accessed via the second path: `api/MyControllerName/SecondActionName`

I tried to create such a route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AbsoleteApiRedirect",
                routeTemplate: "api/MyControllerName/SecondActionName",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "MyControllerName", action = "MyActionName" }
            );
```

But it does not work. The method is not available on this path. In both cases, the methods will have parameters. 
What should be the route for the method to be available at two different urls?

Comment: Make sure that route is added to Routes collection before any other route that can match this URL. Notably before the default one `api/{controller}/{action}`

Comment: @Andrei, You're right! The error was exactly that. I added the route after the default) Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your route is registered after the default one, or some other route that also matches your URL.

MVC always picks the first route that matches the URL at hand. Consider the default one: it has kind of broad pattern, and thus matches lots of URLs, including the one you have in the question. Thus, when adding routes to the Routes collection, make sure the specific ones come before it:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AbsoleteApiRedirect",

....

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
```